# pixate-freestyle-android define style class in XML layout

Tags: android, pixate

I'm using the [pixate-freestyle-android](https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android) library in my app. I want to define style class in XML layout.

In docs I found the following:

```
// Setting a class for a Button
Pixate.setStyleClass(button, "myButton");
```

This is equivalent to defining a class in the XML layout.

```
<Button
    class="myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myButtonStr"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

If I define those programmatically in code - it works. But if I define those in XML layout, like above, Android Studio indicates me "**Unknown attribute class**" at this line and it doesn't work:

```
<Button
    ...
    class="myButton"
    ... />
```

Is it possible to define style class in XML layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute **class="myButton"** can no longer be set in the latest version of library, only programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Put this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.pixate.freestyle"` in your root layout inorder to access the library's class.